# save_post custom post type ? $_POST not working?

Tags: custom-post-types, save-post

i have this code.

```
<?php
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'ct_meta_add');
add_action('save_post','ct_meta_save');
add_action('save_post','ct_parent');
// add meta functions
function ct_meta_add() {
    add_meta_box(
        'ct_chap', //id
        'Thông tin chương', //title
        'ct_meta_show', //callback function
        'chap', //post type     
        'normal' //priority
    );
}
function get_blogspot_url($string) {
    preg_match_all('/<a href="(.*?)"/', $string, $matches);
    $string = '';
    foreach($matches[1] as $val) {
        $string .= $val."\n";
    }
    $string = str_replace('s1600', 's0', $string);
    return $string;
}
// save meta functions
function ct_meta_save() {
    global $post;   
    /* Save meta */
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;
    if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['ct_nonce'], plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) ) return;
    if( !current_user_can( 'edit_post' ) ) return;  
    $meta = array('ct_download_link', 'ct_list_url', 'ct_list_url2');
    foreach($meta as $dt) {     
        if($dt == 'ct_list_url2') {         
            $_POST[$dt] = get_blogspot_url($_POST[$dt]);
        }
        if(isset($_POST[$dt]) && $_POST[$dt] !== '') {
            update_post_meta($post->ID, $dt, $_POST[$dt]);
        } else {
            delete_post_meta($post->ID, $dt);   
        }       
    }   
}
?>
<?php
function ct_parent() { 
    global $post;
    if($_POST['ct_truyen'] && $_POST['ct_truyen'] != "") {
        //lưu hoặc thay đổi truyện của chap
        $ct_post = array();
        $ct_post['ID'] = $post->ID;
        $ct_post['post_parent'] = $_POST['ct_truyen'];  
        //thay đổi thời gian cập nhật truyện
        $tr_post = array();
        $tr_post['ID'] = $_POST['ct_truyen'];   
        $tr_post['post_modified_gmt'] = current_time('mysql');
        $tr_post['post_modified'] = current_time('mysql',7);        
        remove_action('save_post','ct_parent');     
        remove_action('save_post','tr_parent'); 
        wp_update_post($ct_post);   
        wp_update_post($tr_post);   
        add_action('save_post','ct_parent');
    }
}   
?>
<?php //save_meta function
function ct_meta_show() { ?>
    <?php
        global $post;
        $ct_download_link = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'ct_download_link', true) ? get_post_meta($post->ID, 'ct_download_link', true) : '';
        $ct_list_url = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'ct_list_url', true) ? get_post_meta($post->ID, 'ct_list_url', true) : '';
        $ct_list_url2 = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'ct_list_url2', true) ? get_post_meta($post->ID, 'ct_list_url2', true) : '';
    ?>
    <?php wp_nonce_field(plugin_basename(__FILE__), 'ct_nonce');  ?>    
    <table class="form-table">
    <tbody>    
        <tr>
            <th><label for="ct_download_link">Truyện</label><a class="add-chap-truyen" href="<?php echo admin_url('post-new.php?post_type=truyen'); ?>">thêm truyện</a></th>
            <td>
                <?php
                global $post;
                global $wpdb;
                $query = "SELECT ID, post_title FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = 'truyen' AND post_status = 'publish' ORDER BY post_title";
                $results = $wpdb->get_results($query, OBJECT);
                echo '<select name="ct_truyen" id="ct_truyen">';
                if(!$_GET['truyen_id'] || !get_the_title($_GET['truyen_id'])) {
                    echo '<option value = "">None</option>';
                    foreach ($results as $r) {
                        echo '<option value="', $r->ID, '"', $r->ID == $post->post_parent ? ' selected="selected"' : '', '>', $r->post_title, '</option>';
                    }
                } else {
                    foreach ($results as $r) {
                        echo '<option value="', $r->ID, '"', $r->ID == $_GET['truyen_id'] ? ' selected="selected"' : '', '>', $r->post_title, '</option>';
                    }
                }
                echo '</select>';
                ?>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th><label for="ct_download_link">Địa chỉ tải chương</label></th>
            <td><input type="text" name="ct_download_link" class="regular-text" value="<?php echo $ct_download_link; ?>"/></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th><label for="ct_list_url">Địa chỉ ảnh đọc online</label></th>
            <td>
                <label for="ct_list_url">Địa chỉ ảnh 1</label>
                <p><textarea name="ct_list_url" rows="20" class="large-text code"><?php echo $ct_list_url; ?></textarea></p>
                <label for="ct_list_url2">Địa chỉ ảnh 2</label>
                <p><textarea name="ct_list_url2" rows="20" class="large-text code"><?php echo $ct_list_url2; ?></textarea></p>
            </td>
        </tr>        
    </tbody>
    </table>    
<?php } ?>
<?php
//auto chap title
add_filter( 'default_title', 'ct_auto_title');
function ct_auto_title($title) {
    if($_GET['truyen_id'] && get_the_title($_GET['truyen_id'])) {
        $chap_number = get_number_chap($_GET['truyen_id']);
        $title = get_the_title($_GET['truyen_id']) . ' chương ' . ($chap_number+1);
        return $title;
    } else {
        return $title;
    }
}
function ct_remove_excess_columns( $columns ) {

    unset($columns['author']);
    unset($columns['comments']);
    unset($columns['wpseo-score']);
    unset($columns['wpseo-title']);
    unset($columns['wpseo-focuskw']);
    unset($columns['wpseo-metadesc']);  
    return $columns;    
}
add_filter( 'manage_edit-chap_columns' , 'ct_remove_excess_columns' );
?>
```

everything is OK, but when i was saving, the function `get_blogspot_url($_POST[$dt])`
 didn't work because $_POST[$dt].

When i replace `get_blogspot_url($_POST[$dt])` with,

```
get_blogspot_url('<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
<a href="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-sfO5YNlgW0Y/UFCaPberRcI/AAAAAAAAANM/1ccm6QRHxLM/s1600/0000.png" imageanchor="1" style="margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;"><img border="0" height="320" src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-sfO5YNlgW0Y/UFCaPberRcI/AAAAAAAAANM/1ccm6QRHxLM/s320/0000.png" width="240" /></a></div>
<br />
<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
<a href="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-a1bQNURFQU0/UFCaRm88fwI/AAAAAAAAANU/uDnHUsvNvS8/s1600/img000005.png" imageanchor="1" style="margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;"><img border="0" height="320" src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-a1bQNURFQU0/UFCaRm88fwI/AAAAAAAAANU/uDnHUsvNvS8/s320/img000005.png" width="199" /></a></div>
<br />')
```

it works, so i think $_POST[$dt] have problem, can you help me?

You can download php file: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/52812919/chap-meta.rar :(
Sorry about my bad english

Comment: I'm missing something.  What is the value of $dt?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see there is no value set for `ct_list_url2`, when this code block executes,

```
$meta = array('ct_download_link', 'ct_list_url', 'ct_list_url2');
foreach($meta as $dt) {     
    if($dt == 'ct_list_url2') {         
        $_POST[$dt] = get_blogspot_url($_POST[$dt]);
    }
    if(isset($_POST[$dt]) && $_POST[$dt] !== '') {
        update_post_meta($post->ID, $dt, $_POST[$dt]);
    } else {
        delete_post_meta($post->ID, $dt);   
    }
...
```

...in fact that goes for any of the values held with in your `$meta` array. Your posted values are no where to be found so you need to pass them into your function.

Instead try something like,

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $val) { 

    $url = get_blogspot_url($val);

    if(isset($key) && $val !== '') {

       update_post_meta($post->ID, $key, $url);

    } else {

       delete_post_meta($post->ID, $key); 

}
```

You need to be careful though because if any of your submitted POST variables have a `$key` that returns an empty `$val` then your `else` condition will run and delete any meta values stored for the given `$key`. So if there was a value previously stored in that field it will be deleted. Not sure if this is your intended goal?

If you only want to run your `ct_list_url2` POST variable through your `get_blogspot_url` function, excluding the other `$keys` then you can do something like,

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $val) { 

    if(isset($key) && $val !== '') {

        if($key == 'ct_list_url2') {

        $url = get_blogspot_url($val);
        update_post_meta($post->ID, $key, $url);

        } else {

        //uses $val instead of $url to not run through get_blogspot_url() function
        update_post_meta($post->ID, $key, $val); 

        } 

    } else {

       delete_post_meta($post->ID, $key); 

    }

}
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: thanks for your answer but it still not working. @@

Comment: after testing, I recognize the problem is $_POST and preg_match_all? if I set $string = '<div ...' => it's working; if I set $string = $_POST['string'] => it isn't working ?

Answer (score 0):

Just change this line:

```
if(isset($_POST[$dt]) && $_POST[$dt] !== '') {
```

to

```
if(!empty( $_POST[$dt])) {
```

Comment: A little bid content why is this helpful makes a answer much more helpful ;)